# DocuSign Rest API Polling for Status Updates

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am trying to poll DocuSign every 15 minutes to get envelope status updates. 
I'm using the listEnvelopes() method described [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/master/core_recipes/CoreRecipes.java) with some adjustments:

They are setting the lower time constraint like:

```
// set from date to filter envelopes (ex: Dec 1, 2015)
options.setFromDate("2015/12/01");
```

Which would get all of the envelopes since 2015/12/01.

However, in my app, I would like to poll every 15 minutes (as per the DocuSign documentation) via Quartz for the window of the last 20 minutes, with a fromDate that will be dynamically calculated based on the current time.

So I have formatted the date (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm) according to the [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Introduction+Changes/Appendix-Time%20Zone.htm)

However, the only way I can get any envelopes returned is by setting the fromDate property to start of day. (2017-02-17 00:00)

I'm not able to get any results if I add minutes or hours to the date String.( 2017-02-17 20:56) 
I have updated Docusign's settings for timeZones all to eastern time, as that how my my app is configured. It seems to always ignore the hours and minutes values, but yet the documentation recommends polling every 15 minutes. Am I missing something?

I believe I can get time information from the envelope itself (by fetching using envelopeId). That way I might know what time DocuSign thinks it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the format of the from_date for the [listStatusChanges](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/) API

```
options.setFromDate("2017-02-17T20:56:00.000Z")
```

Your GET request will look like this

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes?from_date=2017-02-17T20:56:00.000Z
```

Tip: It is much more efficient to use [Docusign Webhooks](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/status_and_events.html) for getting envelope status changes if your Plan supports it.

> The status of sent envelopes can be determined through the DocuSign webhook system or by polling. Webhooks are highly recommended: they provide your application with the quickest updates when an envelope’s status changes. In contrast, DocuSign limits polling for an envelope’s status to once every 15 minutes or less frequently.
>
> When a webhook is used, DocuSign calls your application, via the URL you provide, with a notification XML message.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the answer and the question. I will give this a try on Monday. What should I call the object oriented api approach that the above link(recipe) illustrates? My hands are tied with regards to the polling method.

Comment: Its called Docusign Connect  or Docusign Webhooks

Comment: Not your link, my link. The CoreRecipes class implementation. Where there is never an explicit GET request made

Comment: I have updated the answer. This line of code in the api recipe makes the actual GET request for you  EnvelopesInformation envelopes = envelopesApi.listStatusChanges(accountId, options);

Comment: @JustinJones Did using the fromDate format that I have provided resolve your issue.